# Modify .zip directory structure using 7zip (prefferably) command line without decompressing

Tags: command-line, compression, zip, 7-zip

Given a .zip with the following example structure:

```
/folder1/
  file1.1.txt
  file1.2.txt
/folder2/
  file2.1.txt
  file2.2.txt
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

I need to be able to modify that internal file structure using 7zip command line tool like so:

**1. I need to move all existing files to a new folder inside the archive (say prefix the stored paths with "/myfolder")**

2. I need to add another folder with other files (outside this question, resolved)

So, without unzipping, I would like to have the following structure as a result:

```
/myfolder/
  myfolderfile1.txt
  myfolderfile2.txt
/data/
  /folder1/
    file1.1.txt
    file1.2.txt
  /folder2/
    file2.1.txt
    file2.2.txt
  file1.txt
  file2.txt
```

I know how to resolve point 2, but point 1 (changing the internal structure) is the one giving me trouble.

The reason for this requirement is that I am working with VERY large and complex archives with the sole purpose of rearranging the files and adding a few more in the same manner to all. It seems counterproductive to unzip for each file (that could take up to an hour) when I could do this easier.

Also, if there is another tool that can perform this task better (i.e. NOT 7zip, but some other **free command line tool**), I am open for suggestions.

Thank you kindly!

*P.S. I am aware there might be a path length problem when increasing the directory path near 248 characters, but that is acceptable.*

Comment: I don't think any tools will have that capability. You might be able to write something yourself using one of the 7zip API wrappers ...